# Shrink middle Row completly before shrinking other rows on browser resize

Tags: html, css

With a basic three row layout:

```
<div class="EditorHeaderWrapper">
   <h1>Title</h1>
</div>

<div class="EditorMainRowWrapper">
 // Main row guts go here
</div>

<div class="EditorFooterWrapper">
</div>
```

How can I make it so that, when the browser height is reduced, the middle row gets complete crushed before the footer (or header) get crushed at all?

```
.EditorHeaderWrapper{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;   
   height:49px;
   background-image:url('blah');
   border-bottom:1px solid black;   
}

.EditorMainRowWrapper{
   position:absolute;
   top:49px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:30px;
   background:#f9f9f4;
   overflow:hidden;
}


.EditorFooterWrapper{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;   
   height:30px!important;
   background:#3c3b37;
   border-bottom:1px solid black;   
}
```

Here's a *working* fiddle using the code above:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZaFp8/3/

But here's the problem: When you put the code in a real browser (FF26) inside the body element (not in a fiddle), with no other styles present, it doesn't work! The footer gets cut off first! So jsfiddle is adding something that fixes the problem.

So I assume I need to add some definitions to the body, html or possibly a wrapper div with some formatting. But what, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Because your footer div is absolutely positioned, you need to assign a min-height of 100% to the body and html elements to "stretch" them to the full height of the window. You also don't really need to absolutely position the other two divs - they will align from top to bottom automatically using relative positioning.

Made a few other tweaks to your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/hoppergrass/ZaFp8/10/

HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="EditorHeaderWrapper">
   <h1>Title</h1>
</div>

<div class="EditorMainRowWrapper">
 // Main row guts go here
</div>

<div class="EditorFooterWrapper">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 html {
    height: 100%;
}

.EditorHeaderWrapper{
   position:relative;  
   height:49px;
   background:#3c3b37;
   border-bottom:1px solid black;   
}

.EditorMainRowWrapper{
   position: relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}

h1 {
   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.EditorFooterWrapper{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;   
   height:30px!important;
   background:#3c3b37;
   border-bottom:1px solid black;   
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   background:#f9f9f4;
}
```

Edit: typos